# Не работает Filter у ADODataSet: "Аргументы имеют неверный тип..."

Tags: ado, delphi

Добрый день! Помогите понять, где ошибка. В Filter у ADODataSet записываю

```
ADODataSet1.Filter:= '(Этап=''ВЫПОЛНЕН'' OR Этап=''Сбыт'') AND Изделие=''ДПД''';
```

Получаю сообщение "Аргументы имеют неверный тип, выходят за пределы допустимого диапазона или вступают в конфликт друг с другом". Имена полей берутся из представления (MS SQL 2005), написаны без ошибок. Такие фильтры нормально работают:

```
ADODataSet1.Filter:= 'Этап=''ВЫПОЛНЕН'' AND Изделие=''ДПД''';
ADODataSet1.Filter:= '(Этап=''ВЫПОЛНЕН'') AND Изделие=''ДПД''';
ADODataSet1.Filter:= '(Этап=''ВЫПОЛНЕН'' OR Этап=''Сбыт'') OR Изделие=''ДПД''';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это вроде глюк (или фича) фильтра. Попробуй:

```
ADODataSet1.Filter:= '(Этап=''ВЫПОЛНЕН'' AND Изделие=''ДПД'') OR (Этап=''ВЫПОЛНЕН'' AND Изделие=''Сбыт'')';
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, так работает!